# Simplifying indefinite integral (possibly in terms of elliptic integrals)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

I would like to simplify the following integral

$$\int ds \frac{s^n}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-(s-s_1)(s-s_2)(s-s_3)}}$$.

for $n=0, 1$, and $2$. Here, $s_1$, $s_2$, and $s_3$ are constants (they come from the roots of a complicated cubic polynomial). I'm pretty sure that this integral can be rewritten in terms of elliptic integrals for each $n$, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this integral can be rewritten in terms of elliptic integrals?

Comment: In addition, you should probably give more information about the cubic polynomial and the constants $s_1, s_2, s_3$. Simply saying that "they come from the roots of a complicated cubic polynomial" is rather vague and unclear.

Comment: I doubt about a possible solution even for $n=0$

Comment: it's a hyperelliptic integral, it cannot be simplified to an elliptic integral

Answer (score 1):

I will write here a (very) partial answer to your problem.

First of all, I am going to consider only one case, that is $n = 0$.
Even in this case, it seems like no expression exists for a "primitive" of that integral.

However if we make a deal (a bad one) we can manage to find an expression. The deal is: one of the three roots must be zero. If that happens, then we have a very nasty expression for the integral.

I will use $a, b, c$ instead of $s_1, s_2, s_3$ to avoid confusion and to write clear.

In the first case, we need to assume $c = 0$ to get an expression for the integral, as said.

$$\int \frac{\text{d}s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-s^2(s-a)(s-b)}} = -\frac{\color{blue}{2 (s-1) s (b-s) \sqrt{\frac{(s+1) (a-b)}{(b+1) (a-s)}} \left(b F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a-1) (b-s)}{(b-1) (a-s)}}\right)|\frac{(a+1) (b-1)}{(a-1) (b+1)}\right)+(a-b) \Pi \left(\frac{a (b-1)}{(a-1) b};\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a-1) (b-s)}{(b-1) (a-s)}}\right)|\frac{(a+1) (b-1)}{(a-1) (b+1)}\right)\right)}}{\color{red}{a (b-1) b \sqrt{1-s^2} \sqrt{\frac{(a-1) (s-1) (a-b) (b-s)}{(b-1)^2 (a-s)^2}} \sqrt{s^2 (a-s) (s-b)}}}$$

Where $F$ denotes the complete Elliptic integral of the first kind and $\Pi$ denotes the complete elliptic integral of the third kind.

---

**Second case**: $n = 1$.

Here we get, assuming $c = 0$ as before.

$$\int \frac{s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-s^2(s-a)(s-b)}}\text{d}s = \frac{\color{blue}{2 \sqrt{\frac{(s-1) (a-b)}{(b-1) (a-s)}} \sqrt{\frac{(s+1) (a-b)}{(b+1) (a-s)}} \sqrt{-s^2 (s-a) (s-b)} F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a+1) (b-s)}{(b+1) (a-s)}}\right)|\frac{(a-1) (b+1)}{(a+1) (b-1)}\right)}}{\color{red}{s \sqrt{1-s^2} (a-b) \sqrt{\frac{(a+1) (b-s)}{(b+1) (a-s)}}}}$$

With the same meaning of $F$ as before.

Again I did not find any expression for $c\neq 0$.

---

**Third Case**: $n = 2$. Always assuming $c = 0$ we have

$$\int \frac{s^2}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-s^2(s-a)(s-b)}}\text{d}s = -\frac{\color{blue}{2 s (s+1) (b-s) \sqrt{\frac{(s-1) (a-b)}{(b-1) (a-s)}} \left(a F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a+1) (b-s)}{(b+1) (a-s)}}\right)|\frac{(a-1) (b+1)}{(a+1) (b-1)}\right)+(b-a) \Pi \left(\frac{b+1}{a+1};\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a+1) (b-s)}{(b+1) (a-s)}}\right)|\frac{(a-1) (b+1)}{(a+1) (b-1)}\right)\right)}}{\color{red}{(b+1) \sqrt{1-s^2} \sqrt{\frac{(a+1) (s+1) (a-b) (b-s)}{(b+1)^2 (a-s)^2}} \sqrt{s^2 (a-s) (s-b)}}}$$

Same meaning of $F$ and $\Pi$.

Again, no expression found for $c\neq 0$.

I apologise for thise answer which does not cover the general cases you presented here. However this could be a start.

Otherwise, you need numerical integration.

**Postface**

I coloured the terms because the writing is rather nasty, and confusing too. In each of the expressions, the results come into a form of fraction: the $\color{blue}{BLUE}$ part is the numerator and the $\color{red}{RED}$ part is the denominator.

Comment: Why is the second radical $\sqrt{-s^2(s-a)(s-b)}$? The OP stated that the constants $a, b, c$ come from the roots of a cubic polynomial, not quartic.

Comment: @cpiegore $a, b, c$ come from a cubic equation which has nothing to do with that one.

Comment: In your first equation above you have $\sqrt{-s^2(s-a)(s-b)}$ in the denominator. This means that $s = 0$ is a double root of the cubic equation, which would imply that at least two of $a, b, c$ must be $0$. If $c = 0$ and $a, b$ are not both zero then the second radical in the denominator should be $\sqrt{-s(s-a)(s-b)}$

Comment: @cpiegore $a, b, c$ have nothing to do with that equation. They are solutions of ANOTHER cubic equation that we do not know anything of.

Comment: But if the factorization of the other cubic polynomial is $-s^2(s-a)(s-b)$ then $s = 0$ is a double root. This means that at least one of $a, b$ must be $0$. If not, then the polynomial must be either quartic or identically zero.

Comment: @cpiegore $a, b, c$ are roots of a cubic equation that we do not anything about. Who cares about THIS factorisation of THIS equation in $s$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138559/discussion-between-cpiegore-and-laplacian).